# Xamarin Http Requests only work on iOS Simulator

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am using `system.net.http` to build a web service layer for my app. I started building this on an iphone simulator (as I develop for iOS first) and everything is working. I checked in my code and then started testing on other devices and nothing works... I get the same exception on a physical iOS device & android physical / emulator.

The Error I get is: `An error occurred while sending the request`

Below is the code I am using to make the request. If I follow the code with breakpoints then it will fail on this line:
`var responce = await client.SendAsync(request);`

```
public class ApiService : IApiService
{

    HttpClient client;

    public List<Group> Groups { get; private set; }

    public ApiService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }

    public async Task<List<Group>> GetGroupsForuser(int userId)
    {

        Groups = new List<Group>();

        //GET http://{server}/groupcontrol/api/group/user/{userId}
        var requestString = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}", Constants.BaseUrl, Constants.kControlURL, Constants.kEndpointAPI, Constants.kEndpointOot, Constants.kEndpointUser, userId);
        var requestUri = new Uri(string.Format(requestString, string.Empty));

        //Set method
        var methodName = "GET";
        var httpMethod = new HttpMethod(methodName.ToUpper());

        //Create request
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUri);

        //Set Headers
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new Authorisation().getAuthToken());

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Printing out complete request: {0}", request));

        try
        {

            var responce = await client.SendAsync(request);//client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Group>>(content);
            } else {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",responce.StatusCode));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(">>>ERROR-------------- {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Groups;
    }
}
```

As stated before the code works on an iOS simulator but NOT a physical device (which is odd). I have updated the info.plist to use arbitrary loads so that shouldn't be an issue. The API I am talking too is being used in a native production iOS app (that I talk too with `NSURLSession`) so the API is not the problem, this is a xamarin issue. I have also given the Android app `Internet` permission.

Has anyone had any experience with this? It's extremely frustrating and I have no idea how to debug it further!

Comment: Did you add permission for Android?

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 yes

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public async Task<string> CallLoginApiAsync(Login login)
> {
>
>     client = new HttpClient();
>     client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
>
>
>
>     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
>
>
>     var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
>
>     var uri = Utils.WebConstants.LOGINURL;
>     int tryCount = 0;
>     try { 
>     while (tryCount <= maxtry)
>     {
>         var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
>
>
>         if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
>         {
>             string resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>
>             return resultString;
>
>
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             if (tryCount == maxtry)
>             {
>                 return Utils.AppConstants.ERROR;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 tryCount++;
>             }
>
>
>         }
>
>     }
> }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         return Utils.AppConstants.ERROR;
>     }
>
>     return Utils.AppConstants.ERROR;
>
> }
> ```

it is working in android.

Answer (score 0):

So I took my failing request out of the `try` block so that I could debug further. I've found out the issue was to do with certificate signing & the address I was using to talk to the app.

First things first Android didn't like a real address and demanded an IP (thanks guys). Second thing I needed to disable certificate checking, I did this with the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    if (cert != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cert);
    return true;
};
```

I placed this just before my request and it now works on all devices. Xamarin strikes again! :D